# Meteor, ChartsJS and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor, chart.js, meteorcharts

I want to iterate through the MongoDB collection to get the chart labels but I get TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'teams[i].name') here is my code:

```
var teams = Teams.find();
var teamNames = [10];

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    teamNames.push(teams[i].name);
}

var chart = new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [teamNames]
```

....

Anyone any suggestions? I am running out of ideas.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think `Teams.find()` returns a cursor. Try `Teams.find().fetch()` to get objects. More here https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
var teamNames = Teams.find().map(
   function(team){
      return team.name;
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`teams` must have a length of less than 10 items. If `teams` is `[{name: "first"}]`, then `teams[1]` will return `undefined` and you will get that error. You can use:

```
for (let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++)
```

to solve this problem.

You can also [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array to get specific properties:

```
labels: teams.map(team => team.name),
```

Comment: That doesn't work... TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'teams[0].name')

Comment: @KlaudiaBojda in that case `teams` is not an array. I think the issue is that you have to call methods on the cursor returned by `.find`

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, the Collection [`.find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find) function returns a [cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor) that you can then use to perform operations on collection items.  In your case, you are treating the cursor as if it were an array which is incorrect.  There are a few different ways that you can approach this.

1) Use [`.forEach()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-forEach) to iterate over the cursor.

```
var teamNames = [];

Teams.find().forEach(function (e) {
  teamNames.push(e.name);
});
```

2) Use [`.fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-fetch) to return all matching documents in an array, then iterate over that.

```
var teams = Teams.find().fetch();
var teamNames = [];

for(i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
  teamNames.push(teams[i].name);
}
```

3) Use [`.map()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-map) to iterate over the collection calling the callback on all items and returning an array.

```
var teamNames = Teams.find().forEach(function (e) {
  return e.name;
});
```